# Navicat rename field in model and sync to server without drop

Tags: mysql, navicat

I created a model from a database schema's tables. It's working correctly, but when I rename a column in a table and after that I sync to the server. Navicat recognize the changes and show the SQL queries which needed to be executed. The queries are the following:

- disable foreign key checks
- drop indexes
- create column with new name
- drop old column
- recreate previously dropped indexes with the currently created column
- enable foreign key checks

How can I force Navicat to not drop columns, just rename them?

Thanks in advance, kukko.

Comment: It is better to ask this question to Navicat support. You also can try to rename this column in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/), the 'Refactor' feature will change dependent objects on renaming (foreign keys, views, routines...).

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation. I will try it out soon. :)

Comment: @Devart It's totally meets my our needs. Thanks for the recomendation! Navicat can't do that, but dbForge can rename fields and tables instead of drop and recreate them. If you add this as an answer I would accept it as solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at object editors in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). There is possibility to rename the field with dependent object modifications.

Here it is another simple way to rename the column:

- select column in Database Explorer
- press F2 (Rename command) and enter new name
- choose Rename or Refactor (with dependent objects modifications)

Answer (score 0):

By simply executing the statement to rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE your_tablename CHANGE column_name new_name datatype other_options_like_nullable;
```

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE badname newname INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: I want to rename columns through the modeller, not by writing queries manually.